# Comparing in PHP if today is between 2 different dates if so then print a value

Tags: php, date, drupal, for-loop, while-loop

I am new in php.
I have 2 dates that I am getting from 2 drupal fields and each field is saved in database with it´s own date format so the formats:

`$old_format_starts` -> has this date format: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`  and

`$old_format_ends` -> has this date format: `date('jS F Y H:i:s');`

So I am using the following code:

```
$old_format_starts = $entity->field_video_available_d[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$old_format_ends =  $entity->field_video_until[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

After that, I am converting those date information to this date format: date('Y-m-d'); like this:

```
$starts =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old_format_starts));
$ends = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_format_ends));
```

In order later I can use that information for comparing if today is between the dates $starts and &ends, and if today is between those dates then I will print something.
So here is the total code that I am using, but I have problems with the date formats... something I am doing wrong because the page is just taking long time in load the page and in the end it does not load.... The problem is coming when I am using the WHILE bucle, because I tried just using the code before the WHILE and the page loads in a normal way. So I dont know If I am using wrong the `WHILE` BUCLE or the `strtotime` function or `date`s format...?

```
<?php
$old_format_starts = $entity->field_video_available_d[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$old_format_ends =  $entity->field_video_until[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

$starts =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old_format_starts));
$ends = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_format_ends));

$to= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($to));
$i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($starts));
while ($i <= $ends) {
   if ($i==$to) {
       print date('Y-m-d', strtotime($i));
       break;
    }
    $i=date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 day', $i));
}

?>
```

I really have tried already many ways.. but without success.... here is the same code but using the FOR bucle... and also without success..

```
<?php
$old_format_starts = $entity->field_video_available_d[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$old_format_ends =  $entity->field_video_until[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

$starts =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old_format_starts));
$ends = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_format_ends));

$to= date("Y-m-d");
for ($i = $starts; $i <= $ends; $i++) {
   if ($i==$to) {
       print $i;
       break;
    }
}
?>
```

PLEASE HELP!!!! Any sugestion is welcome!!! There has to be a solution... Something I am doing wrong in the bucles `(While)` or `(FOR)` because the page is not loading!!!

Thank you!!! :)

Comment: What does _bucle_ mean?

Comment: I have no idea, but I *think* he means a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop is not necessary here
I suggest the use of the DateTime native class like this :

```
    $old_format_starts = $entity->field_video_available_d[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $old_format_ends   = $entity->field_video_until[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

    $starts = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_format_starts);
    $ends   = DateTime::createFromFormat('jS F Y H:i:s', $old_format_ends);
    $today  = new DateTime() ;

    if(($today > $start) && ($today < $end)){
        //Do your thing
    }
```

Comment: Actually I tried your code only until the $today = new Datetime(); line of code in order to check if the problem was with the (if) but it was not!! The error is with the DateTime. Now the page is not loading and brings the next error: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in eval()

Comment: Hello guys!! Thanks to both of you!! Problem solved!!! I took Amine´s sugestion and it worked. I was just printing in a wrong way the results. Thanks Amine!

Answer (score 2):

If you compared the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) values directly, it would work. `strtotime()` returns simple integers and `>/</=` type comparisons will work as expected. In your code, you're converting them to strings using [`date()`](http://php.net/date), in a least-significant-value-first ordering, so your comparisons won't work as expected.

**Comparing the dates using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)**:

```
$start =  strtotime($old_format_starts);
$end = strtotime($old_format_ends);
$today = time();

if ($today > $start && $today < $end) {
    // code
}
```

**Comparing the dates using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/date) class:**

```
$start =  new DateTime($old_format_starts);
$end = new DateTime($old_format_ends);

if ($today > $start && $today < $end) {
    // code
}
```

Once the comparison is over, you can format the date strings using [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function (if you're using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)) or the [`format()`](http://php.net/datetime.format) method (if you're using `DateTime` class).